# Scanner not working correctly in Mac OSX terminal

Tags: java, macos, io, intellij-idea, java.util.scanner

I have a hacky Ant command a user can run that does some stuff.  This command prompts a user for input.  In IntelliJ, when testing, it works correctly.  But when I run the ant target from the terminal, I get weird behavior.  Here is the code:

```
    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    writer.println(error + "  If you continue with the load, some data may be in a corrupted state.  Would you like to continue? (y/n): ");
    writer.flush();
    String userResponse = userIn.next();
    while (!(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("n")
      || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("yes") || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("no"))) {
      writer.println("Invalid input.  Please specify if you would like to continue with the load. (y/n): ");
      writer.flush();
      userResponse = userIn.next();
    }
    return userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");
```

When running the ant command from the terminal, the error message is properly displayed but then when the user enters input, either nothing happens, or I have to press enter a bunch of times for anything to process. It also refuses to read in the input correctly.  If I type yes it still loops forever, prompting for inputs as if the user gave invalid input.

Is this some kind of bug?  Am I inept at using scanner?

EDIT: I have tried using nextLine() instead already.  Sometimes, but not consistently I get a java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found exception.  Other times, it works if I press enter 10+ times.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem where my program (run via ant) would create a scanner but when asked for input, the program would seem to just loop and not accept any input until I terminated with ctrl+c. Turns out the problem was the "fork" attribute in my build.xml file. I had fork="yes" and I changed it to "no" or just took it out entirely the scanner worked just fine. Hope this helps!